# React 17.0.1 Form onChange skips the last number

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, express

I have from with input type number, which has an pretty simple onChange function when entered a value the last number is missed out

Example:

If 99 is type in the input box, only 9 is recorded, and when 2523 is typed in the input box 252 is been recorded, the last number is been skipped

Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chandrasekhar-gg5iy?file=/src/App.js)

inside of onChange function

```
const handleRequestingCost = (e, index) => {
setCostsFormValues({
  ...costsFormValues,
  [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
});

for (const key in costsFormValues) {
  const mappedData = {
    [key]: costsFormValues[key][0]
  };
  mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
  const list = [...row];
  const item = list[index];
  if (item) {
    item.requestingCost = mappedDataArray;
    setRow(list);
  }
}
...
```

What I am missing here? Or if is this the bad way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

setState is async. So you are reading `costsFormValues` before it is updated

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [costsFormValues, setCostsFormValues] = useState({});
  const [row, setRow] = useState([
    {
      index: 5399,
      name: "user name",
      quantity: "1000",
      remainingQty: 2000,
      requestingCost: [],
      budgetedCost: [
        {
          key: "Labour Cost",
          value: 176
        },
        {
          key: "Material Cost",
          value: 890
        }
      ],
      amountForQuantity: [
        {
          key: "Labour Cost",
          value: 150
        },
        {
          key: "Material Cost",
          value: 570
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  const handleRequestingCost = (e, index) => {
    const mappedDataArray = [];
  
    setCostsFormValues({
      // set all cost value in each array
      ...costsFormValues,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
    });
    const updatedFormValues = {     // added this local variable which holds latest value update
      // set all cost value in each array
      ...costsFormValues,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
    };
    for (const key in updatedFormValues) {
      // loop each array and merge into one object
      const mappedData = {
        [key]: updatedFormValues[key][0]
      };
      mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
      const list = [...row];
      const item = list[index];
      if (item) {
        item.requestingCost = mappedDataArray;
        setRow(list);
      }
    }
    console.log(updatedFormValues);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make changes to a local variable rather than setting the state object directly as it takes about 300-500ms to update after the setState() call; as it creates queues for performance optimization.

Please refer to the code snippet:

```
 const handleRequestingCost = (e, index) => {
    const mappedDataArray = [];
    let TempValue = {};

    TempValue = {
      ...TempValue,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
    };
    for (const key in TempValue) {
      // loop each array and merge into one object
      const mappedData = {
        [key]: TempValue[key][0]
      };
      mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
      const list = [...row];
      const item = list[index];
      if (item) {
        item.requestingCost = mappedDataArray;
        setRow(list);
      }
    }
    console.log(TempValue);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

As `setState` is async, you should use the value just after mutate it, that why we have `useEffect` hook to do it instead

```
 const handleRequestingCost = (e, index) => {
    const mappedDataArray = [];
    setCostsFormValues({
      // set all cost value in each array
      ...costsFormValues,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
    });
    for (const key in costsFormValues) {
      // loop each array and merge into one object
      const mappedData = {
        [key]: costsFormValues[key][0]
      };
      mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
      const list = [...row];
      const item = list[index];
      if (item) {
        item.requestingCost = mappedDataArray;
        setRow(list);
      }
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(costsFormValues);
  }, [costsFormValues]);
```

The console will show the right value, but be careful with my snippet, your `handleRequestCost` do some stuff with `costsFormValues` you should pass it to `useEffect` as well

```
 const handleRequestingCost = (e, index) => {
    setCostsFormValues({
      // set all cost value in each array
      ...costsFormValues,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const mappedDataArray = [];
    console.log(costsFormValues);
    for (const key in costsFormValues) {
      // loop each array and merge into one object
      const mappedData = {
        [key]: costsFormValues[key][0]
      };
      mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
      const list = [...row];
      const item = list[index];
      if (item) {
        item.requestingCost = mappedDataArray;
        setRow(list);
      }
    }
  }, [costsFormValues]);
```

Something like this, but there is the `index` that I didnt get from you logic yet